# How to find an element value based on another elements attribute value in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to learn XPath, and finding it difficult, as I am Googling my way through it all. 
Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <details>
        <signature id="sig1">
            <name>mr. Barry Smith</name>
            <telephone type="fixed">01234 123456</telephone>
            <telephone type="mobile">071234562</telephone>
        </signature>

        <signature id="sig2">
            <name>mr. Harry Smith</name>
            <telephone type="fixed">01234 123456</telephone>
        </signature>
    </details>
```

How can I find the names of people who have a mobile phone, I can get either or, but not both.

I have been trying things like this:

```
staffdetails/signature/telephone[@type='mobile']name
```

Also, is there a reference guide for using XPAth, so I can easily figure out any query I wish? Using online tutorials I have found explain how XPath works, but the examples don't cover enough.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
//signature/name[following-sibling::telephone[@type='mobile']]
```

It reads as:

> Select any `name` that has a `signature` parent and a `telephone` sibling which `type` = `mobile`.

Regarding the reference, I actually learnt the most from [the examples in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)!

Comment: That is great! Thanks, it works perfectly. I will accept the answer once it allows me. How did you figure it out? I have a lot of query's to learn, is there a go to list of examples that cover all different types of XPath querys I can use? Cheers!!

Comment: @deucalion0 It's not that hard once you get used to it :). There are some tricky parts one should know about, and then it's all the same. Really, I leartn the most from the spec examples I linked in the answer, that should be enough to pull you through the initial bumps. After that, it's a smooth ride.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to use `following-sibling::` or nested predicates here.  Just do this:

```
/details/signature[telephone/@type = 'mobile']/name
```